# why laravel say table dosent exsit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'app.infos' doesn't exist.

**home controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\info;

class homeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $data=info::all();
        return view('home',['data'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

**web php**

```
Route::get('home', [homeController::class ,'index']);
```

Comment: because the table doesn't exist

Comment: What is the table name? Since the model name is `info`, it's looking for the plural of that, which is `infos`. If that's not your table name, [then you'll need to specify it in the model](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#table-names)

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Answer (score 2):

change your table 'info' to 'infos' or just add (protected $table = 'info') to your model

Answer (score -3):

Make sure table name is "infos" not info

After that run following command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: i don't know i just have table with name info but he say infos ...and if i ceart other like test laravel say tests always s

Comment: ok, add (protected $table = 'info';) in your model

Comment: thank so much she work

Comment: That's basically what aynber's comment says